Send an email via PHP using third part services mailjet
I want to send an email via my localhost PHP after a specific action is completed.
In the given code, I am testing emails statically to check if it works.
I tried this code:
<?php

require_once "../../../vendor/autoload.php";

use \Mailjet\Resources;
//passed in my actual api keys
    $mj = new \Mailjet\Client('api_key','secret_key',false,['version' => 'v3.1']);
    $body = [
        'Messages' => [
        [
            'From' => [
            'Email' => "x@gmail.com",
            'Name' => "name"
            ],
            'To' => [
            [
                'Email' => "y@gmail.com",
                'Name' => "name"
            ]
            ],
        'Subject' => "Hello from Mailjet",
        'TextPart' => "Greetings from Mailjet!",
        ]
        ]
    ];

try {

    if( $mj->post(Resources::$Email, ['body' => $body])){
        echo "Email sent successfully!";
    }else{
        echo "Email doesnt sent!";

    }
    
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}


?>


It's returning : Email sent successfully!
but, in reality, the email never gets delivered

You should look a what is in the response. That should give you some clue.
$response = $mj->post(...)  and then var_dump($response->getData()); and also getReasonPhrase();

if( $mj->post...just validates that some kind of non-false response was received to the post() method. It doesn't tell you what's in that response. Your code seems to assume that post() returns a simple true or false, but it doesn't. Also, while these 3rd party mail services can be very good, even if the API service accepted your mail for sending still doesn't 100% guarantee that the recipient's mailserver will accept it for delivery! Email can be complicated, you may need to be patient.

Did you log into your MailJet account? to check the statut of thos email? Bounce,...

If your code is not failing, this suggests that it reached the email host and was able to send the message to the host. If the email never arrives, this suggests an issue in the host sending the message. You should check for message tracking with your host or search for other event logs or errors.
